# Visual Studio C++ Issue (c++ version of .bat doesn't work)

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, visual-studio-2013, registry

when I run things via batch as built-in administrator I have no issues. I purchased Visual Studio since I love to code and help people by using programming to solve problems but I ran into some issues.

Some things appear to not be working. For example, in Windows command line, I can do something basic like dir command to see the contents of a directory, but if I do it in C++ via system command such as:

```
system("CHDIR C:\\Windows\\Windows\\System32\\Sysprep&&dir");
```

the directory contents do not get displayed.

I am running as built-in administrator and have disabled firewall/antivirus on the test computer (no network). I have removed inheritance and gave full control to everyone for the specified folder and files and ensured there were no deny entries.

I have ran into other potentially similar issues as well. For example, reg query from within system from C++ works but reg add does not. I removed /f and it prompted it to overwrite and I selected yes and it appeared to work but the registry value did not change. If I simply run the batch file it works.

Then I tested basic file operations. I tried del command from within system and when it couldn't find the file I thought I should try to not use system() methods. I was suggested to try remove and/or DeleteFile and both did not work.

I created a win32 console empty project for testing. I set release and ran the .exe it created as built-in administrator. Does anyone know why the batch files simply work but I can't get the C++ code to work?

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe because CHDIR is a cmd.exe built-in?

Comment: Is it the "chdir", "dir" or both that don't work? When I tried it the directory contents get displayed but the current directory doesn't change.

Comment: If the system call runs  cmd.exe, then the current folder will get changed in that cmd.exe.

Comment: C++ != batch file. What works in one does not magically work in the other, just like "ride bike" != "fly plane" even though both contain pedals and hand-controlled steering.

Comment: Changing the directory does not work here because there is most likely no directory C:\Windows\ **Windows** \System32\Sysprep. And if application is executed from a different drive than drive C the command `cd` requires parameter `/D` or it won't work. And last why not using directly `dir C:\\Windows\\System32\\Sysprep` in C++ source code?

Comment: @Martin James chdir works. I use it to run programs such as system("CHDIR C:\\Windows\\System32\\Sysprep&&config.exe");

Comment: @uesp If I use them on C:\temp they work but for system folders it doesn't. I need it to work for system folders as well and other examples mentioned.

Comment: @Ken White Please don't spam my topic if you don't know C++.

Comment: @Mofi I copied line twice and didn't delete completely in this forum post. It is Windows only once.

Comment: @ComputerSecurity: First, you have no control over who comments (or answers) here; this is a public site. Second, never *assume* you know something you don't (like my knowledge of a topic). Third, my comment is correct, whether you agree or not. DOS batch commands don't work from C++, unless you launch `cmd.exe` and pass it a **batch file** via that command line. Fourth, be polite here; it's both required by the guidelines and plain common sense. You're asking **us** for free help to solve **your** problem; being rude or insulting is a poor idea.

Comment: If anyone has any C++ examples for modifying registry or reading/editing files in system folders please feel free to share.

Comment: @Ken White I'm not trying to run batch files from C++, I'm looking for ways to perform certain tasks using C++ such as modifying registry and files. I have working batch files that never give me any problems which work without issues when ran as domain admin but for what I'm doing now I want to create more complex software and ran into issues when using C++. If anyone knows how to do things using C++ please feel free to help. Thanks.

Comment: It appears as if even though I'm running the program as administrator, it's not running with administrator permissions.

Comment: I am aware of that, and I'm explaining that you can't simply use **batch commands** from your C++ code. You have to write the equivalent WinAPI calls to perform those tasks. Batch files use the command processor (cmd.exe) to do so, but without that command processor you have to **write the code yourself** to accomplish those same tasks. You have to programmatically (not using `system()`) change the directory, and then use `FindFirstFile` and its relatives to iterate the files in the directory and collect a list, et cetera.

Comment: I mentioned this already in my first post. I tried the C++ commands remove and DeleteFile but they did not work. If I use it on a folder like C:\temp which my program creates and adds file there then those files can be edited/deleted. I'm trying to figure out why a simple batch can delete a file but from within the C++ program it doesn't work. It looks as if my program is not running with administrator rights.